# Canvas returns null on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, canvas

why when I am refreshing page canvas value is null

```
function App() {
  let cavnas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  console.log(cavnas);//after refreshing no value is null 
  return <canvas id="canvas" className="border-4  border-sky-500"></canvas>;
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to read the #canvas element from the DOM, two lines before it writes the #canvas element into the DOM.  It's returning null because there's nothing there yet.